# "13 Reasons Why" vs "Thirteen Reasons Why"

Tags: support, tags

I propose that the tag ["Thirteen Reasons Why"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thirteen-reasons-why) is renamed to the correct "13 Reasons Why", since [this is the title Netflix uses](https://www.netflix.com/title/80117470). "Thirteen Reasons Why" is [the title of the book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteen_Reasons_Why).

Perhaps there should be a synonym tag since the title is stylized as "Th1rteen R3asons Why"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had two question with [thirteen-reasons-why](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thirteen-reasons-why) and one with [13-reasons-why](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/13-reasons-why), now they have been merged while keeping the original show title as primary one.

Synonym tag [th1rteen-r3asons-why](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/th1rteen-r3asons-why) is also created.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged as [status-completed]?